# Entity Relationship Diagram: What is a composite ID .Net Core 6

Tags: sql, erd, asp.net-core-6.0

I have 3 tables in the database and I wanted to know what a composite primary key is.

E.g:
Table 1 is called superheroes
Table 2 is called categories of superheroes
and table 3 is called biography of superheroes

I want to create an ERD (Entity Relations Diagram)

[image]

The attribute key is supposed to retrieve the json file and display the superhero category as needed, is it possible or am I completely wrong?

This for a .net core project to learn

Comment: How looks is the structure of your tables?

Comment: A composite key is basically a key that is made up out of multiple fields.

Comment: **1.** Forget about JSON for the moment. When dealing with relational databases, JSON is nothing that belongs there at first. Later, once you know what you are doing, you may introduce some JSON columns for tree data, but maybe you never want to. **2.** In your diagram it seems that a category can only be applied to one hero, while a hero can belong to multiple categories. You probably want it vice versa. (But maybe it's a diagram type that has 1 and n reversed.) **3.** Tell us about the biographies. Can there be only one biography per superhero? Can a biography cover multiple superheros?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner On your point 2. Yes, I wanted the relationship reversed. I'm sorry, it was my mistake. I added the biography because there can only be one biography per superhero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composite keys are seldom used with technical IDs. They are more common with natural keys.

There are superhero categories. You'll have a table for these categories and probably give each category a number, so you can uniquely identify a category with this. You could just as well use the category name as a unique identifier, but then you'll have problems if you want to use a different name some time, e.g. rename 'Ability to fly' with 'Flying ability'.

Then there are superheros. You'll have a table for them and each superhero will either get an ID or simply be identified by their unique name. One of these two columns will be the primary key. Let's say you use the superheros' names.

As there is no separate table mapping superhero categories to superheros, you'll have the category ID in the superhero table, so each superhero belongs to exactly one category.

If you want a superhero to belong to multiple categories, you'll need a bridge / association table for this. In your ERM you may only show the superhero and the category table and use an m:n relation arrow or show all three tables with 1:n relations. This is just a matter of the granularity you want to show in your diagram.

Now let's say your biography table can contain multiple biographies per superhero. This means there must be the superhero name in the biography table to establish this relation. The unique key for a row in this table would probably be the combination of superhero and biography author. Two columns combined identify a row. A composite key. And if you make this the primary key, you'll have a composite primary key.

Comment: Thanks solved it. It wasn't as hard as it looked. Thanks again